# iReport compile error found when click on the preview

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to iReport and tried to generate a report using iReport. The problem I got was not compiling the jasper file.

This is the error I got. How can I fix this? I have already set the fonts, and cannot preview the report anyway.

```
Compiling to file... C:\Users\SDU\Desktop\ugc test\report1.jasper
Errors compiling C:\Users\SDU\Desktop\ugc test\report1.jasper!
Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@1e398a0
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
calculator_report1_1442307421307_832861: 192: expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 192, column 37.
1 error 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:113)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:201)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:270)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:563)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:528)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
calculator_report1_1442307421307_832861: 192: expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 192, column 37.
1 error 
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:161)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:900)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:540)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:517)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:109)
    ... 7 more  Compilation running time: 32!
```

Comment: There are some errors you have not included, so perhaps you need to add those in. Also, "Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions" suggests you have a syntax error in one of your expressions. Perhaps make a copy of the file, and delete elements from your report until you get a different problem - you need to narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: Seems like you have overlapping elements. Pleas look into report those elements  must be highlighted as red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you use Text Field instead of Static Text somewhere.
Text Field accepts only expressions.
It can generate errors like this.